# Error symfony 4 al crear proyecto

Tags: symfony

Recién instalado el cli de symfony en debian  vía wget, al crear un nuevo proyecto con *symfony new project -- full*, me aparece el siguiente error:

> *Executing script cache:clear [KO]  [KO] Script cache:clear returned with error code 1 !!  Could not open input file: ./bin/console !!
>
>   Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd
>                                                                  unable to run /usr/local/bin/composer create-project
>
>   symfony/website-skeleton /home/dwes/proyectoFinal : exit     status 1*

Composer genera la estructura de directorios excepto bin, intento ignorar el error pero obviamente al utilizar cualquier comando php bin/console no puede abrirlo:

> *root@dwes2daw:/home/dwes/proyectoFinal php bin/console make:controller Could not open input file: bin/console*

Gracias por vuestro tiempo

Comment: Gracias a Roger Torné por su edición de la pregunta.

Comment: Hola xino_92, bienvenido. Tu composer.json tiene post-install-cmd/post-update-cmd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fue un problema con https://github.com/symfony/recipes. Lo han arreglado y ahora puedes crear tu proyecto.

Gracias a:
Śwież4k